# I want to run teambuild's unit tests (more than once) against multiple different databases

Tags: unit-testing, tfsbuild

I want to run teambuild's unit tests (more than once) against different databases, e.g. I want to test my build compiles, then run the same suite of tests against SQLServer, then Oracle etc. databases.

I'm pretty sure I could do something clumsy like build/test against 1st config file then build/test against 2nd config file etc. but I'm looking for something more elegant (preferably without the pointless 2nd recompilation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want seperate unit tests (these are considered system tests, really - since they are involving a database) for each database type.  If the same unit test can fail for 1 DB platform and pass for another, then it is not telling you anything specific enough when you look at the pass/fail status and the history of the test results for that test over time.

Otherwise, consider decoupling or abstracting the db connection in such a way that you can programmatically change it while setting up the test (see [ClassInitialize()] and [TestInitialize()] attributes in the MSTEST [unit test framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517.aspx)).

The elegant solution is to not depend on the databases for unit tests;  create seperate tests for the databases that check the data returned by the queries and procedures you are calling.

Visual Studio 2010 Premium has the [capability of running unit tests to verify data and behaviour of SQL Server 2005 (and later) DBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172118.aspx). I would be suprised if you could not also find a tool to test Oracle Dbs or roll your own system of testing what is returned (something like [ndbUnit](http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) might help)

Comment: thanks for your answer. we're decoupled... we've got a separately tested DAL which is tested against each db we support, after that's tested though I'd just be happier watching the remaining tests pass against each db.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share examples of  the pattern you have / come up with for the benefit of the community since I noticed that others have similar questions among the stack exchange sites;  You might post it on Code Review and get some valuable feedback too!